# All permalinks go to products page with WP E-Commerce plugin?

Tags: e-commerce, plugin-wp-e-commerce

I realize that maybe this isn't the best place to ask this, but since getshopped.org (the makers of the plugin) don't seem to have any support form, AND since I am unable to access the forums I'm posting here...

After installing WP E-Commerce to test how it works, I discovered that all links to blog posts and pages on my site go to the WP E-Commerce page.

I've looked at the FAQ and nothing seems to fix this problem of all my links going to the wrong place now.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If it does, please delete your comment and make it a proper answer. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Permalinks in settings were set for default. Changing them to /%category%/%postname%/ fixed my problem and now all posts and page permalinks go where they are suppose to.

Answer (score 1):

You just have to go in settings-permalinks

then you enter: `/%category%/%postname%/` or if you choose something else keep it.

Then just re-save all. Even if you have already the good setting, just re-save, and it will work.