# Permalink issue only with numbers

Tags: plugin-wp-e-commerce

I use wp-e-commerce plugin and when I write a url like "mysite.com/event/testevent" very thing is ok and wordpress shows the correct page. In case that the event is a number like "mysite.com/event/123456" wordpress shows me the products page. [I follow this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/56237/all-permalinks-go-to-products-page-with-wp-e-commerce-plugin) 
 but my issue continues to exist.

Comment: Had you inquired with plugin's developers? Do you have same issue with regular posts (honestly I am not sure if it works in general) ?

Comment: Yes, this happens also with the regular posts, but in this case appears all the posts.

Comment: I will debug the template to see what happen with arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately numeric slugs seem to be not supported by WordPress, see long running trac ticket [#5305 (permalinks broken when article name is numeric)](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/5305).